# Installed new Sensi Thermostat, Everything Works Except No Cold Air

Tags: thermostat

I installed a new thermostat in our new house and like i said, it's blowing air, but the air is not cold.  Here's how it was set up when it was working:

[image]

Here's what Sensi said to do on the app as I installed it:

[image]

It's installed exactly like the image.  When I get home I can post a picture of it.  Here it is:

[The new one installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yp5ag.jpg)

How should I begin troubleshooting this?  What other information can I provide you all?

Thanks a bunch!!!

Comment: Do you have 24VAC between the red and brown wires in your thermostat cable?

Comment: The thermostat works? Does the system work in heating mode? What's the make and model of the heat pump? Can you show the wiring at the air handler?